# Android: Open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p' in native code in a non rooted phone

Tags: android, android-ndk, alsa

I'm trying to create a native android application which should work with non rooted devices. The goal of this application re-route and modify audio mixer paths. And for the time being im testing my code in a rooted phone and planning to test it in a non rooted one.

Firstly i have these in my /dev/snd folder (device = motorola g4). So it can be clearly seen that the device I'm trying to open is there (pcmC0D1p)

```
comprC0D24 hwC0D16    hwC0D9     pcmC0D13c  pcmC0D17c  pcmC0D21c  pcmC0D4p  
comprC0D9  hwC0D32    pcmC0D0c   pcmC0D13p  pcmC0D17p  pcmC0D22c  pcmC0D5p  
controlC0  hwC0D34    pcmC0D0p   pcmC0D14c  pcmC0D18c  pcmC0D23c  pcmC0D6c  
hwC0D10    hwC0D37    pcmC0D10c  pcmC0D14p  pcmC0D18p  pcmC0D25p  pcmC0D6p  
hwC0D1000  hwC0D5     pcmC0D10p  pcmC0D15c  pcmC0D19c  pcmC0D2c   pcmC0D7p  
hwC0D13    hwC0D6     pcmC0D11c  pcmC0D15p  pcmC0D1c   pcmC0D2p   pcmC0D8c  
hwC0D14    hwC0D7     pcmC0D12c  pcmC0D16c  pcmC0D1p   pcmC0D3c   timer     
hwC0D15    hwC0D8     pcmC0D12p  pcmC0D16p  pcmC0D20c  pcmC0D3p
```

And my native C code extracts which has the issue is as follows.

```
struct mixer_ctl *ctl;
const char* device = "/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p";
mixer = mixer_open(device);
```

And the mixer_open function

```
struct mixer *mixer_open(const char *device)
{
    struct snd_ctl_elem_list elist;
    struct snd_ctl_elem_info tmp;
    struct snd_ctl_elem_id *eid = NULL;
    struct mixer *mixer = NULL;
    unsigned n, m;
    int fd;
    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        ALOGE("Control open failed\n");
        return 0
    }
}
```

So my problem that the "open(device, O_RDWR);" fails with the following log. No matter when tested in a rooted or non rooted phone.

```
Control open failed --> this is my log :)
09-27 01:19:40.843 24403-24403/? W/ee.playbacktest: type=1400 audit(0.0:323): avc: denied { search } for uid=10117 name="snd" dev="tmpfs" ino=7893 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:audio_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

So I have some questions regarding this.
1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Will this method work on a non rooted phone. (directly accessing sound devices)
3. Does anyone knows a third party libraries which can provide functionalities similar to amix and aplay in ALSA library.

Comment: The stack trace points at `libamix.so`, whatever that is. How is that related to your `mixer_open` function?

Comment: Oh yes, My bad. Edited.

Comment: That log entry reports on a SELinux violation. You may try to study your Android device's SELinux rules, but the answer will probably boil down to "SELinux says no". On Android, access to hardware devices tends to be mediated through services that check your app's permissions first.

Comment: By "App's permissions" do you mean android runtime permissions? I have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_PHONE_STATE, MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS. Does this means we cannot access this devices through native code directly?

Comment: The diagram at https://source.android.com/devices/audio seems to suggest that what you are doing will never work on un-rooted devices, as you cannot bypass SELinux there.

Comment: Ok, yes it seems so. Thanks.